# Fetching google spreadsheet ios

Tags: ios, google-sheets, google-drive-api

How can you fetch a google spreadsheet to an app?  I uploaded a cdv file that i converted to google spreadsheet but now i'm trying to fetch the file and it's throwing a 1003 error.

The problem is there's no downloadUrl anymore.  Where could it have gone?

Answer (score 1):

Documents in Google-native formats such as Spreadsheet cannot be downloaded, instead you have to use the `exportLinks` collection to export them in a supported format:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents